# How to work with real time in custom function block on ST in Codesys 3.5

Tags: plc, st, codesys

I am trying to accomplish very simple task, but it looks like I cannot figure our how.

My task is daily schedule. output `Q1` have to be `HIGH` every day from 1:00 to 2:00. I could not find function block that would help me. I decided to create my own.

Here are my definitions.

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK Shedule
VAR_INPUT
    EN: BOOL;

    MO: INT;
    TU: INT;
    WE: INT;
    TH: INT;
    FR: INT;
    SA: INT;
    SU: INT;

    T1: STRING;
END_VAR
VAR_OUTPUT
    Q: BOOL;
END_VAR
```

The idea is this. `EN` is input. It should be `HIGH` for output `Q` to become `HIGH` too.

Others are days of the week. I can set 1 or 0 if I want Schedule work on that day. Pretty much universal function block to create any type of schedules.

**Question 1**: When I make week day variables type `BOOL`, when I add block to the LD line, it creates contact for every week day parameter.

[image]

**What can I do to make only `EN` contact connected to the line?**

If I try to add function block with EN/ENO, then I do not know

1) How do I know inside function block that `EN` is `HIGh` or how do I get access to that variable?
2) I cannot connect coil to my `Q` output. it only connects to `ENO`. how do i control state of `ENO`?

But that is not all. I added Time and Date library

[image]

But only thing I found to work with time is `RTCLK.GetDateAndTime` function block. And i cannot figure out how to work with it.

My simple task is to get current TIME only and current day of the week and if this week is enabled and current time in the range in input `T1` - make `Q` = `HIGH` otherwise `LOW`.

**Any hints on that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function block as follows which will be called cyclically (e.g. every 60sec):

1. Reset your control bit at the beginning (you will set this bit too high if the
   current day and time is inside your specified interval)
2. Read the current date and current time of the system clock of the
   CPU (Controller)
3. Extract the actual time and actual day. Check if the actual time is
   inside your specified interval (e.g. 1:00 to 2:00) and set your control bit
   appropriate

You should use library functions for the handling of the day and time values. Maybe you should check out the free library [OSCAT BASIC](http://www.oscat.de/). The website is in German but the documentation and the software is in English.

Comment: Finally I've got it working. The key suggestion was OSACT BASIC. I have managed to get realtime bit I think I am getting it wrong. Could you show example how to read PLCs real time?

Answer (score 0):

This example is used to read the plc time and converts it to a string. This code was developed for a Siemens PLC with SCL (Structured Control Language):

```
(*************************************************************************************)

FUNCTION  FC11 : STRING

TITLE = 'Convert date and time to string'


(*******************************************************************************

 FUNCTION: Convert date and time to string

*******************************************************************************)

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// parameter
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

VAR_TEMP

DTAsString          : STRING[14];

DateTime            : DATE_AND_TIME;
DateTimeAsByteArray AT DateTime
                    : ARRAY[0..7] OF BYTE;

ReturnValue         : INT;

Year                : INT;
Month               : INT;
Day                 : INT;
Hours               : INT;
Minutes             : INT;
Seconds             : INT;

END_VAR

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Inizialize 
DTAsString  := '';

//Read PLC date and time 
ReturnValue := READ_CLK(CDT := DateTime  // OUT: DATE_AND_TIME
                        );

//Split data and time value    
Year        := BCD_TO_INT(DateTimeAsByteArray[0]);
Month       := BCD_TO_INT(DateTimeAsByteArray[1]);
Day         := BCD_TO_INT(DateTimeAsByteArray[2]);
Hours       := BCD_TO_INT(DateTimeAsByteArray[3]);
Minutes     := BCD_TO_INT(DateTimeAsByteArray[4]);
Seconds     := BCD_TO_INT(DateTimeAsByteArray[5]);

//Build string
//------------

//Year
//----
IF (Year >= 10) THEN
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= '20');
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= RIGHT(IN:= INT_TO_STRING(Year),L:=2));
ELSE
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= '200');
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= RIGHT(IN:= INT_TO_STRING(Year),L:=1));    
END_IF;    

//Month
//-----
IF (Month >= 10) THEN     
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= RIGHT(IN:= INT_TO_STRING(Month),L:=2));
ELSE
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= '0');
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= RIGHT(IN:= INT_TO_STRING(Month),L:=1));        
END_IF;

//Day
//---
IF (Day >= 10) THEN
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= RIGHT(IN:= I_STRNG(Day),L:=2));
ELSE
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= '0');
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= RIGHT(IN:= I_STRNG(Day),L:=1));
END_IF;

//Hours
//-----
IF (Hours >= 10) THEN
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= RIGHT(IN:= I_STRNG(Hours),L:=2));
ELSE
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= '0');
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= RIGHT(IN:= I_STRNG(Hours),L:=1));
END_IF;

//Minutes
//-------
IF (Minutes >= 10) THEN
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= RIGHT(IN:= I_STRNG(Minutes),L:=2));
ELSE
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= '0');
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= RIGHT(IN:= I_STRNG(Minutes),L:=1));
END_IF;

//Seconds
//-------
IF (Seconds >= 10) THEN
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= RIGHT(IN:= I_STRNG(Seconds),L:=2));
ELSE
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= '0');
    DTAsString :=  CONCAT (IN1:= DTAsString, IN2:= RIGHT(IN:= I_STRNG(Seconds),L:=1));
END_IF;

//Return Date and Time as String
//------------------------------    
FC11 := DTAsString;

END_FUNCTION

//*******************************************************************************

(* Nothing beyond this *)
```

Comment: What is READ_CLK? Where did you take that function?

Comment: The system functions (SFC) SFC 1 "READ_CLK" is contained in the operating systems of the Siemens CPUs of the S7-300 and S7-400.
With SFC 1 "READ_CLK" (read system clock), you read the current date or current time of the system clock of the CPU.
On the other hand with SFC 0 "SET_CLK" (set system clock), you set the time and the date of the CPU clock.
Normally functions like this should be provided by the PLC manufacturer and are part of the operating system which is running on the PLC.
What kind of system (PLC) you are using?

Comment: Now I get it. This is supported by siemens. Unfortunately not by may PLC which is OWEN.

Comment: The PLC must be equipped with a “Real Time Clock” (RTC) and the manufacture must provide functions to read and write the RTC.